# DNSServiceNATPortMappingCreate always returning error code -65540

Tags: ios, upnp

I'm doing an ios application, it starts a server and listen for incoming connections, the device running the application may be behind a router so I need to make a port forward.
I'm trying to make a port forward using DNSServiceNATPortMappingCreate but its always returning error code -65540

```
DNSServiceRef *sdRef = NULL ;
void ( *DNSServiceNATPortMappingReply) (DNSServiceRef sdRef,
                                        DNSServiceFlags flags,
                                        uint32_t interfaceIndex,
                                        DNSServiceErrorType errorCode,
                                        uint32_t externalAddress,
                                        DNSServiceProtocol protocol,
                                        uint16_t internalPort,
                                        uint16_t externalPort,
                                        uint32_t ttl,
                                        void *context );

DNSServiceNATPortMappingReply = &DNSServiceNATPortMappingCreate_callback ;

DNSServiceErrorType error = DNSServiceNATPortMappingCreate(sdRef,
                                                           0,
                                                           0,
                                                           kDNSServiceProtocol_TCP,
                                                           htons(2000),
                                                           htons(5000),
                                                           0,
                                                          DNSServiceNATPortMappingReply,
                                                           NULL
) ;
```

and this is the callback

```
void DNSServiceNATPortMappingCreate_callback(
                                         DNSServiceRef sdRef,
                                         DNSServiceFlags flags,
                                         uint32_t interfaceIndex,
                                         DNSServiceErrorType errorCode,
                                         uint32_t externalAddress, 
                                         DNSServiceProtocol protocol,
                                         uint16_t internalPort, 
                                         uint16_t externalPort, 
                                         uint32_t ttl, 
                                         void *context )
{
    printf("in callback\n") ;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the docs for [DNSServiceDiscovery](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/networking/Reference/DNSServiceDiscovery_CRef/DNSServiceDiscovery_CRef.pdf), the error code -65540 means `kDNSServiceErr_BadParam`.

The docs for `DNSServiceNATPortMappingCreate` suggest that you have to allocate storage for the `DNSServiceRef` passed as the first argument.  i.e. You need to change

```
DNSServiceRef *sdRef = NULL ;
DNSServiceErrorType error = DNSServiceNATPortMappingCreate(sdRef, ...
```

to

```
DNSServiceRef sdRef;
DNSServiceErrorType error = DNSServiceNATPortMappingCreate(&sdRef, ...
```